# Mac : Restore default python version

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I installed Anaconda, python changed in that given by this distribution and I used it happily.

Now I want to build some libraries (e.g. Fenics) and I need the default Mac version of python.

What can I do?

Comment: It [looks like](http://fenicsproject.org/download/) you can use `conda` to install Fenics.

Comment: Great that worked! But I'm still interested  to know how to restore the default version of python.

Comment: To do that, you'll need to play with `$PATH`. Anaconda inserts itself in your path, pre-empting the system python. I don't know that it provides any way to remove itself from the path -- you might have to do so manually. Alternatively, you can use something like [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to install anaconda and manage your environment. Then it would be as simple as `pyenv global system` to go back to to system python, and `pyenv global anaconda-X-X-X` to go back to anaconda.